# How to get JSON string for each distinct field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables DbContours:

```
_|ContourId                           |
1|CDCBC42E-2E86-426E-A9BA-00B8B902A153|
2|FDDD2AC5-172D-4A7B-8106-00D05EC1F41C|
```

and SimpleLines:

```
_|SimpleLineId|X1    |Y1    |X2    |Y2    |ContourId                           |
1|Guid        |number|number|number|number|CDCBC42E-2E86-426E-A9BA-00B8B902A153|
2|Guid        |number|number|number|number|CDCBC42E-2E86-426E-A9BA-00B8B902A153|
3|Guid        |number|number|number|number|FDDD2AC5-172D-4A7B-8106-00D05EC1F41C|
4|Guid        |number|number|number|number|FDDD2AC5-172D-4A7B-8106-00D05EC1F41C|
```

One row in DbContours has multiple corresponding rows in SimpleLines via field ContourId in SimpleLines table. I managed to write query to get all rows in SimpleLines that have ContourId from table DbContours:

```
SELECT [X1], [Y1], [X2], [Y2] FROM [DDROPDATABASEPROM-2020-10-11-13-13].[dbo].[DbContours] 
INNER JOIN [DDROPDATABASEPROM-2020-10-11-13-13].[dbo].[SimpleLines] 
on [DDROPDATABASEPROM-2020-10-11-13-13].[dbo].[DbContours].ContourId = [DDROPDATABASEPROM-2020-10-11-13-13].[dbo].[SimpleLines].ContourId
order by [DDROPDATABASEPROM-2020-10-11-13-13].[dbo].[DbContours].ContourId
```

I Want to get json string of all SimpleLines for each distinct ContourID (resulting Select must contain multiple rows of json string based on distinct ContourId) . How to do it?

I think it must be something like this, but for each ContourId and not particular:

```
DECLARE @Lines NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT [X1]
      ,[Y1]
      ,[X2]
      ,[Y2]
  FROM [DDROPDATABASEPROM-2020-10-11-13-13].[dbo].[SimpleLines] WHERE ContourId = 'CDCBC42E-2E86-426E-A9BA-00B8B902A153' FOR JSON AUTO);
DECLARE @OriginalJSON NVARCHAR(4000), @newjson VARCHAR(100);
SET @OriginalJSON = '{"CalculationProvider":"CalculateWithCSharp"}';
SELECT JSON_MODIFY(@OriginalJSON, '$.SimpleLines', JSON_QUERY(@Lines)) AS 'Updated JSON';
```

Each resulting JSON string should look like this:

```
_| ResultingStrings
1|  {"ContourId":"CDCBC42E-2E86-426E-A9BA-00B8B902A153","SimpleLines":[{"X1":6.62,"Y1":2.11,"X2":6.61,"Y2":2.12},{"X1":5.53,"Y1":3.1,"X2":5.52,"Y2":3.15}]}
2|  {"ContourId":"FDDD2AC5-172D-4A7B-8106-00D05EC1F41C","SimpleLines":[{"X1":6.62,"Y1":2.11,"X2":6.61,"Y2":2.12},{"X1":5.53,"Y1":3.1,"X2":5.52,"Y2":3.15}]}
```

Comment: Please add some info about input, and desired output, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want *...to get json string of all SimpleLines for each distinct ContourID...* and the *...resulting Select must contain multiple rows of json string based on distinct ContourId...*, a possible approach is to generate a JSON output for each `ContourId`:

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE DbContours (
   ContourId uniqueidentifier
)
INSERT INTO DbContours (ContourId)
VALUES
   ('CDCBC42E-2E86-426E-A9BA-00B8B902A153'),
   ('FDDD2AC5-172D-4A7B-8106-00D05EC1F41C')

CREATE TABLE SimpleLines (
   ContourId uniqueidentifier,
   X1 numeric(4, 2),
   Y1 numeric(4, 2),
   X2 numeric(4, 2),
   Y2 numeric(4, 2)
)
INSERT INTO SimpleLines (ContourId, X1, Y1, X2, Y2)
VALUES
   ('CDCBC42E-2E86-426E-A9BA-00B8B902A153', 6.62, 2.11, 6.61, 2.12),
   ('CDCBC42E-2E86-426E-A9BA-00B8B902A153', 5.53, 3.1,  5.52, 3.15),
   ('FDDD2AC5-172D-4A7B-8106-00D05EC1F41C', 6.62, 2.11, 6.61, 2.12),
   ('FDDD2AC5-172D-4A7B-8106-00D05EC1F41C', 5.53, 3.1,  5.52, 3.15)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT  
   (
   SELECT 
      dc.ContourId,
      (SELECT X1, Y1, X2, Y2 FROM SimpleLines WHERE ContourId = dc.ContourId FOR JSON AUTO) AS SimpleLines
   FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
   ) AS ResultingStrings    
FROM DbContours dc
```

Result:

```
ResultingStrings
{"ContourId":"CDCBC42E-2E86-426E-A9BA-00B8B902A153","SimpleLines":[{"X1":6.62,"Y1":2.11,"X2":6.61,"Y2":2.12},{"X1":5.53,"Y1":3.10,"X2":5.52,"Y2":3.15}]}
{"ContourId":"FDDD2AC5-172D-4A7B-8106-00D05EC1F41C","SimpleLines":[{"X1":6.62,"Y1":2.11,"X2":6.61,"Y2":2.12},{"X1":5.53,"Y1":3.10,"X2":5.52,"Y2":3.15}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the resulting JSON string is quite straightforward, you can just use the `FOR JSON AUTO` clause as any joined tables will get created as nested JSON objects:

```sql
SELECT
    DbContours.ContourId
    ,SimpleLines.X1
    ,SimpleLines.Y1
    ,SimpleLines.X2
    ,SimpleLines.Y2
FROM DbContours
LEFT JOIN SimpleLines ON DbContours.ContourId = SimpleLines.ContourId
FOR JSON AUTO
```

which returns this JSON array:

```json
[
    {"ContourId":"CDCBC42E-2E86-426E-A9BA-00B8B902A153","SimpleLines":[{"X1":6.62,"Y1":2.11,"X2":6.61,"Y2":2.12},{"X1":5.53,"Y1":3.10,"X2":5.52,"Y2":3.15}]}
   ,{"ContourId":"FDDD2AC5-172D-4A7B-8106-00D05EC1F41C","SimpleLines":[{"X1":6.62,"Y1":2.11,"X2":6.61,"Y2":2.12},{"X1":5.53,"Y1":3.10,"X2":5.52,"Y2":3.15}]}
]
```

If you want to return each `ContourId` as a separate row, use the `OPENJSON` table-valued function as follows:

```sql
DECLARE @x NVARCHAR(MAX) = (
    SELECT
         DbContours.ContourId
        ,SimpleLines.X1
        ,SimpleLines.Y1
        ,SimpleLines.X2
        ,SimpleLines.Y2
    FROM DbContours
    LEFT JOIN SimpleLines ON DbContours.ContourId = SimpleLines.ContourId
    FOR JSON AUTO
)

SELECT [key], value
FROM OPENJSON(@x)
```

which returns:

```
key | value
----|-------
0   | {"ContourId":"CDCBC42E-2E86-426E-A9BA-00B8B902A153","SimpleLines":[{"X1":6.62,"Y1":2.11,"X2":6.61,"Y2":2.12},{"X1":5.53,"Y1":3.10,"X2":5.52,"Y2":3.15}]}
1   | {"ContourId":"FDDD2AC5-172D-4A7B-8106-00D05EC1F41C","SimpleLines":[{"X1":6.62,"Y1":2.11,"X2":6.61,"Y2":2.12},{"X1":5.53,"Y1":3.10,"X2":5.52,"Y2":3.15}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to construct the JSON is something like this

```
select  
  dc.ContourId,
  (select X1, Y1, X2, Y2 from #SimpleLines where ContourId = dc.ContourId for json path) as SimpleLines
from #DbContours dc
for json path, without_array_wrapper;
```